# (Django) how to submit a form with empty fields?

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I have a form with a drop down list with two options ("MCQ" and "SEQ") and some fields. Selecting "MCQ" would hide  fields used by "SEQ" and vice versa. I want to submit this form but the "please filled out this field" notice pops up. What should I do to submit this form?

I've searched around Stack overflow before looking possible solutions, some suggested placing "required" or "disabled" beforehand, however I would like a dynamic way of doing if possible but based it on which option the user selects since the user might leave everything empty and just submit if nothing is required.

Additional Information:

1. I'm using forms.ModelForm, the fields came from there.
2. I'm using js to hide and show the relevant fields.

I Appreciate any help/suggestions. :)

Comment: I would do it in js. you can edit these in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your model should not define those fields as required, this way they can be empty when the form is validated:

```py
class MyModel:
   my_field = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, length=500)
   ...
```

`blank=True` will tell your forms not return an error if this field is empty

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I've stopped using form, instead, I've decided to request.Post() to obtain what I need from the html page :). I realized what I wanted to created was too dynamic and complicated to simply use form/formset. Thank you for the help nevertheless!